# Invert SeekBar values and with a logarithmic / exponential scale

Tags: android, math, seekbar

I want a `SeekBar` that meets the following requirements:

```
min = -655
half = -140
max = 0
```

Following the next [explanation](http://van-uffelen.com/blog/?p=291) I've managed to have

```
min = 0
half = 140
max = 655
```

I am halfway there but I don't know how to have the numbers inverted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the expression you came up with, and reflect it horizontally around x=.5 by replacing x with 1-x.  Then reflect it vertically around y=0 by negating the whole thing.

That is, you have f(x), but you want g(x) where g(x) = -f(1-x).